# Using Tags Instead of Categories for site structure

Tags: html, design

I noticed that huffingtonpost.com and some other websites are using tags instead of categories for blog structure.

For example the last tag in [this post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/04/29/apple-icloud_n_855649.html) (like every post) is redirecting to "technology news" section of the menu. Is it OK to use tags instead of categories in the wordpress menu? what's the advantage of doing this with tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is neither inherent advantage nor inherent disadvantage in using Tags versus Categories. Tags and categories are merely *taxonomies*, which are used to describe content.

Tags and Categories don't actually provide site "structure", though their index pages can be added to custom Nav Menus.

The primary difference between Categories and Tags is that Categories can be hierarchical, whereas Tags cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I have always used categories to force structure on people making posts. I would create X number of categories and all content must be filed under one or more of those categories. As such, I could have a simple menu that is controlled by me to dictate the different categories that you can browse. Then, as a way of offering the contributors a way to determine their own organization, tags can be input by the contributor as they see fit. I do not dictate what tags can and cannot be present. By building a tag cloud or tag search, the content can thus also be structured by tags.

In sum, I use categories to force structure on contributors and tags to allow them to dictate structure.